# Transfer Data Between Two MySQL Databases Without Unnecessary Schema Changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-transfer

I have two databases with a large number of tables in each.

`database A` is a empty and `database B` has around one thousand records.

`database A` has some extra tables that `database B` doesn't, for instance `database B` has a `students` table and a `parents` table, while `database A` has those *and* a `course` table.

The two databases have the same table names, but `database A` has more columns in each table than `database B`. For example, the `students` table of `database B` includes columns for `name`, `age`, and `address`, but the corresponding table in `database A` has those columns in addition to `country`, `sex`.

When I try to transfer data using dreamsql, the extra columns in `database A` are deleted. How can I transfer my data between two tables without incurring changes to the database schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It's just like manual Insertion...
No need to get confused

```
     var con = new DatabaseAEntities;
        var names = con.names;

        SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=G:\DataBaseB.sdf");

        foreach(var name in names)
        {
        string x = name;
        cn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO names(Name) VALUES(@Name)", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", x);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully");
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not much into programing..so can i do it using any kind of software ??